# Inconsistent Accessibility with Properties.Settings?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to code a quick program and the error shows up when I assign Properties.Settings to variable s.
I am trying to assign it to this variable because a lot of my text boxes need to be assigned with a value of the setting and also because there is a lot of settings which need saving.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SharpDock
{
    public partial class SettingsWindow : Form
    {
        public Properties.Settings s = new Properties.Settings(); // This is the error.
        public SettingsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            app1.Text = s.app1;
            app2.Text = s.app2;
            app3.Text = s.app3;
            app4.Text = s.app4;
            app5.Text = s.app5;
            app6.Text = s.app6;
            ico1.Text = s.ico1;
            ico2.Text = s.ico2;
            ico3.Text = s.ico3;
            ico4.Text = s.ico4;
            ico5.Text = s.ico5;
            ico6.Text = s.ico6;
        }

        private void abutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app1 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("SharpDock", "You must restart the program for the changes to take effect.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void abutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app2.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app2 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void abutton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app3.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app3 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void abutton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app4.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app4 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void abutton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app5.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app5 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void abutton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
            ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                app6.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.app6 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico1 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico2.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico2 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico3.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico3 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico4.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico4 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico5.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico5 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ibutton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
            ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";
            DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ico6.Text = ofd.FileName;
                s.ico6 = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'SharpDock.Properties.Settings' is less accessible than field 'SharpDock.SettingsWindow.s'   C:\Users\Lewis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SharpDock\SharpDock\SettingsWindow.cs  14  36  SharpDock
```

Please help! I am stuck with this error.

~Lewis

Comment: Don't post all of your code only the part that is causing the error. Also you can condense a lot of those methods into 1 or 2 methods.

Comment: Try to declare `s` as `private` or `internal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Properties.Settings.Default and you don't need to instantiate a variable for it. If you want an alias to make the code smaller, remove this code:

```
public Properties.Settings s = new Properties.Settings();
```

And add this before the class declaration:

```
using s = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

And as deathismyfriend commented, you could reduce a lot your code by creating methods for the repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Settings` are saved inside `Properties.Settings.Default` so you should use it instead of declaring your own settings. Also, you can subscribe multiple controls to the same event. What you should do is, subscribe all of your `abuttons` to `aButton_Click` event and `ibuttons` to `iButton_Click` event. Here is your code fixed:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SharpDock
{
    public partial class SettingsWindow : Form
    {
        public SettingsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings();
        }

        private void LoadSettings()
        {
            app1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app1;
            app2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app2;
            app3.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app3;
            app4.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app4;
            app5.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app5;
            app6.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.app6;
            ico1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico1;
            ico2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico2;
            ico3.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico3;
            ico4.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico4;
            ico5.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico5;
            ico6.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ico6;
        }

        private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("SharpDock", "You must restart the program for the changes to take effect.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                ofd.Filter = "Executable Files (*.exe) | *.exe";
                ofd.Title = "Which executable would you like to launch?";

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (sender == abutton1)
                    {
                        app1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app1 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == abutton2)
                    {
                        app2.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app2 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == abutton3)
                    {
                        app3.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app3 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == abutton4)
                    {
                        app4.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app4 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == abutton5)
                    {
                        app5.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app5 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == abutton6)
                    {
                        app6.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.app6 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void iButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png) | *.png";
                ofd.Title = "Which icon would you like?";

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (sender == ibutton1)
                    {
                        ico1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico1 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == ibutton2)
                    {
                        ico2.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico2 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == ibutton3)
                    {
                        ico3.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico3 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == ibutton4)
                    {
                        ico4.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico4 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == ibutton5)
                    {
                        ico5.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico5 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                    else if (sender == ibutton6)
                    {
                        ico6.Text = ofd.FileName;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.ico6 = ofd.FileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need items that you're referencing from your settings to be set inside your settings:

[image: Settings picture]